# Is there a way to remove "Please Review & Act on These Documents" section from DocuSign's embedded UI?

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to remove "Please Review & Act on These Documents" section from DocuSign's embedded UI?

[image]

I understand I may not be able to remove the "Please read the Electronic Records..." etc. but how about the section directly above that? I don't need to display a logo or any text or the sender's name or company. Can this be done?

**UPDATE:** Here is a DocuSign demo of this very thing: http://sedemo1.cloudapp.net/GennWatt/embedded.html

Comment: Duplicate question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661091/edit-docusign-signing-landing-page

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. You can edit the verbiage with the signing resource file, the node is `<data name="DocuSign_WelcomeDialogHeader">Please Review &amp; Act on These Documents</data>`

Comment: Why, then, is it missing in this example? http://sedemo1.cloudapp.net/GennWatt/embedded.html

Answer (score 0):

The linked example users a standard web form to push values into a DocuSign Powerform and prepopulates those values through query string parameters within the Powerform call.
Please see the example here - page 15,16,17.
https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/powerforms-user-guide.pdf

When they actually enter the signing ceremony, they would still be shown the standard signing experience (v1.1).