# Edit DocuSign Signing Landing Page

Tags: docusignapi

Once a user clicks on the email requesting they sign the document and is taken to the landing page; there is a message "Please Review & Act on These Documents".

Underneath there is a user image and next to it it says "Docusign" the "Mr" underneath it.

How do I get either this box to disappear or ideally edit it such that instead of it showing just "Mr" it shows the name of the user who has been messaged?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hide that green are box by modifying the signing resource file inside your branding.

[image]

[image]

For more details refer to page 28 and 29 of [DS Signing Resource file](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-signing-resource-file-v2-0)

Comment: I have updated it. But it is not applied to power form

Comment: For Powerforms I think you need to apply on Captive Signing Resource File

Comment: Yes, I had done it. Now I have done this by selecting the default action on my created brand. Then it will be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

The top bold name is what you had put in the name of the user. That can be modified either when you send the envelope, if you are the sender, or if you are the signer, you need to modify it in your preference for your account (after you log in to the Developer Sandbox).
The "Mr" is the account name, which you have set for yourself when you created this account. To change it, you need to go to the admin and under account profile you can change it.

Hope that helps.